# Big O notation for (n^2)

Tags: java, big-o, time-complexity

example 1

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        System.out.println(count++);
   }
}
```

example 2

```
for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {            
     System.out.println(count++);
}
```

Both example give me a Big O (n^2). but which ans is the best?

Comment: Didnt get you, what do you mean by best?

Comment: I think the second is the best, it will better when you assign `n=n*n`, and then `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`  !

Comment: second is best option like you dont need to loop further if you know the expected behaviour

Comment: Best ans for what purpose?

Comment: "Clear sky is blue and blue paint is blue but which is best?" makes as much sense. What are you asking? Best for what?

Comment: both answers are same except that your first example uses an extra variable j.

Comment: The first: `2 + 3n + 3n^2` and the second `2 + 4n^2` !

Comment: even if example 2 is the same as 1, I should use example 1 to prevent overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the loops are same only. There is no best. But if `N` value is large then `N*N` value will overflow and you need to move back to two for loops. So you can use this as per your `N` value.

Comment: Assuming that `count` starts out at 0, then if `N*N` is going to overflow, `count` is also going to overflow.

Answer (score 2):

To find the *best* code, it would be better to compile it and use `javap -c ClassName.class` to see the generated bytecode for both methods. I used `foo` method for the former and `bar` method for the latter.

```
public static void foo(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            System.out.println(count++);
        }
    }
}

public static void bar(int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {
        System.out.println(count++);
    }
}
```

These are the results:

```
public static void foo(int);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: istore_1      
       2: iconst_0      
       3: istore_2      
       4: iload_2       
       5: iload_0       
       6: if_icmpge     38
       9: iconst_0      
      10: istore_3      
      11: iload_3       
      12: iload_0       
      13: if_icmpge     32
      16: getstatic     #2       // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      19: iload_1       
      20: iinc          1, 1
      23: invokevirtual #3       // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      26: iinc          3, 1
      29: goto          11
      32: iinc          2, 1
      35: goto          4
      38: return        

public static void bar(int);
    Code:
       0: iconst_0      
       1: istore_1      
       2: iconst_0      
       3: istore_2      
       4: iload_2       
       5: iload_0       
       6: iload_0       
       7: imul          
       8: if_icmpge     27
      11: getstatic     #2       // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      14: iload_1       
      15: iinc          1, 1
      18: invokevirtual #3       // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      21: iinc          2, 1
      24: goto          4
      27: return
```

In the end, the latter implementation seems to be *better* than the former due to less operations made.

I'm not an expert on this, so if anyone can edit/perform a better analysis, feel free to do it. I wrote this answer since it didn't fit inside a single comment.

Comment: `less operations made`: Same to you, up !

Answer (score 0):

When you say best, In programmatic sense, there are 2 ways to define, In terms of memory and performance(Usually iterations).

In terms of memory, second one is best because only 2 variables are used(i and n).
Along with that only one assigning of the variable(i++ => i = i+1) happens for every iteration.
whereas in first one, i++ and j++, two assigning operations happens for every iteration.
As reassigning of the variables also takes considerable amount of time in high processing operations, second one is best.

In terms of iterations, both are same.